# Is POST non idempotent when it returns 409 on duplicates?

Tags: rest, post, idempotent

Usually POST is non idempotent. 
But if, for example, database doesn't allow duplucates (user registration), then POST adds a user on the first call and then when performing again returns 409. Is POST idempotent in this case?  I mean, does this behavior meet the definition of idempotency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a HTTP method is defined as non-idempotent, it means that there are not guarantees.

However, any of these methods can still have idempotent behavior. It's just that generic clients can't assume either way.

Similarly, if a method is defined as non-safe, they might still not have side-effects.